# Why does Autoencoder take the input data as label data as well

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I was following a guide to build a basic, single layer autoencoder to learn Keras as well as autoencoders. However I realised that the model takes `X_train` data as both input data and label data during the training and it is actually same with `X_test` in the evaluation. I also checked another example autoencoder code and they had the same structure as well.

Is this because autoencoder takes the data as it is, like the label is data itself there is no specific label? What is the reason behind this, couldn't we just run the model without any label given at all (I actually tried this but Keras did not like the idea and gave an error)?

Training and evaluation calls are the followings

```
autoencoder.fit(X_train,X_train, epochs=nb_epoch, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, verbose=0)

test_predictions = autoencoder.predict(X_test)
print('Test reconstrunction error\n', sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(X_test, test_predictions))
```

**Note:** my data is just randomly created, normally distributed 5d data if that has any effect

**Edit:** Thank you all it was my bad/confusion, as I said in the comments, I have completely overlooked the part that the system will compare the reconstructed output with the label data. As the comparison is said to be done with the input data when talked verbally. However in the built system the error is calculated with the difference between the label data given and the output

Comment: Do you know what autoencoders supposed to do? And do you know in supervised learning there always should be some labels, in order to network learn from?

Comment: @Kaveh, I am new to these topics but yes, and my question is emerging from right there. Please correct me if I am wrong, I am just trying to learn. Autoencoders try to extract features from the input data such that the data can still be reconstructed from the extracted features (preferably with the minimal error). However in this process Autoencoders does not use externally provided labels but they adjust their training process based on the minimalization of the reconstruction error, therefore they are considered unsupervised. So I was wondering why we are providing the data itself as label

Comment: you are answering your question in the comment. So imagine you want to find a function to map some n-dimensional data into an m-dimensional space. how would you know if your representation in the embedding space is meaningful? One way is to try to do the same process backwards, meaning mapping the embedding representation into the data itself. If you are able to achieve this with the whole train dataset, that means, with a high probability you found a meaningful representation of your data. In other words, you have found a good function to map the data in embedding space

Comment: Thank you @hamid.khb I completely overlooked the part that the system will compare the reconstructed output with the label data. As the comparison is said to be done with the input data when talked verbally. However in the built system the error is calculated with the difference between the label data given and the output

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, the input data is the label data. Comparing the label with the output is the same as comparing the reconstruction with the actual data (input). If it doesn't answer your question, try to explain more, what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoencoders aim to compress input data into reduced, meaningful parameters and decode them back to the input data. Therefore, the model is well trained when it manages to reproduce exactly the input data. For this reason, the y label is the input data itself and the loss that you get as output is a measure of similarity between what you want to predict (the input data itself) and what your model actually produces

Comment: Thank you, I completely overlooked the part that the system will compare the reconstructed output with the label data. As the comparison is said to be done with the input data when talked verbally. However in the built system the error is calculated with the difference between the label data given and the output